Why is the mapping degree given by $\int_{\mathbb R^2} \mathrm{det}(u|\partial_1 u|\partial_2 u) \, \mathrm dx$
I am currently reading the paper „Existence of Two-Dimensional Skyrmions via the Concentration-Compactness Method“ by Lin and Yang and in there, they define the mapping degree of a function $u : \mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb S^2 \subset \mathbb R^3$ via
$$\mathrm{deg}(u) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \int_{\mathbb R^2} u\cdot (\partial_1 u \times \partial_2 u) \, \mathrm dx$$ and I cannot see why this is the mapping degree of $u$.
My ideas to tackle this is by using the formula $a \cdot (b \times c) = \det(a|b|c)$ which would translate to $$u\cdot (\partial_1 u \times \partial_2 u)  = \det(u|\partial_1 u|\partial_2 u) = \det(u|\mathrm Du),$$ and I found references (e.g. the paper „ Sobolev maps on manifolds: degree, approximation, lifting“ by Mironescu) that write down that given a function $v:\mathbb S^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb S^2$ the degree can be computed via $$\mathrm{deg}(v) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_{\mathbb S^2} \det(\mathrm Dv,v) \, \mathrm d\omega.$$
These two formulas are very close but not quite the same: the domain of integration is different, and the differential operators are different.
Moreover, I have not found a reference proving the formula involving $\det(\mathrm Du,u)$.
The identification of $u:\mathbb R^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb S^2$ as a function $u: \mathbb S^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb S^2$ seems reasonable as (basically by assumption) $$\lim_{|x| \to \infty} u(x) = (0,0,1),$$ which might link the two formulas above. But again, the differential operators are different.
So my questions are: Can anyone explain why the first formula is the mapping degree? And can anyone please provide a reference for the degree formula (with proof) involving the integrated $\det(\mathrm Du,u)$?
Thank you very much =)
